# Mock HttpResponseMessage while unit testing API with Moq and AutoFixture

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api2, moq, autofixture

I am writing unit tests for the existing Web API 2 project. For which i am using `Ploeh Autofixture` and `Moq`.

**Test Method :**
   **UPDATED**

```
 [Test]
    public async Task Service1_TestMethod() {

      //some code here
     var fakeemail = FakeBuilder.Create<string>("test1234@test.com");
      var fakeUserInvite =
                FakeBuilder.Build<UserInvite>()
                    .With(i => i.EmailAddress, fakeemail)
                    .With(i => i.Username, fakeemail)
                    .Create();
      var fakeUserToken = FakeBuilder.Create<string>();
      var fakeHttpResponseMessage =
                    Fixture.Build<HttpResponseMessage>()
                                 .With(h => h.StatusCode, HttpStatusCode.OK).Create();
  //Here i am mocking another service method. Whose response is HttpResponseMessage.
  Service2.Setup(i => i.AddUser(fakeUserInvite, fakeUserToken))
            .ReturnsAsync(fakeHttpResponseMessage);

  var result = await Service1.AddUser( /*   */);

}
```

**Service1 Method :**

```
   public async Task<bool> AddUser(/*   */)
   {
    var response = await Service2.AddUser(userInvite, userToken); // response is null even after mocking it.

   // Add user code follows bassed on the above response.  

   }
```

If i comment the `Service2.AddUser` call then everything works. There is a lot of code in that method apart from this call. I am having problem with only this call. If this call returns the mocked `HttpResponseMessage` then everything works.

`Service2` is an external API. I am just wondering how to `mock` `HttpResponseMessage`. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting any exception? If yes, which one?

Comment: No exception. Just the `response` is null for the call `Service2.AddUser`. I want the `response` to be the object `fakeHttpResponseMessage` which i mocked while `setup` the call.

Comment: How are `fakeUserInvite` and `fakeUserToken` being passed to the `Service2.AddUser` method? The actual call being made needs to use those same objects in order for Moq to return your `fakeHttpResponseMessage`. See [matching arguments](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#matching-arguments) in the Moq documentation.

Comment: Those 2 parameters are created by `AutoFixture` and passed to `Service2.AddUser`.  Those 2 parameters are valid types otherwise `Service2.Setup` will throw compile time error. Updating question with these objects creation.

Comment: Is `Service2.AddUser` a static method? If not, how is the `Service2` test double being passed to `Service1`?

Comment: `Service2.AddUser` is not a static method. `Service2` is a Mock of original `Service2`, which is injected to `Service1` through `Unity`.

Comment: `Service2` has other methods which return types other than `HttpResponseMessage`. They are working fine.  Only `AddUser` method is giving problem as it is returning `HttpResponseMessage`. I think there is something tricky in mocking `HttpResponseMessage`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121239/discussion-between-venky-and-enrico-campidoglio).

Comment: Please proved a [mcve] so others can reproduce and understand the problem to provide better assistance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The stub you create with:

```
service2.Setup(i => i.AddUser(fakeUserInvite, fakeUserToken))
        .ReturnsAsync(fakeHttpResponseMessage);
```

requires the actual call to be made with the exact *same* objects as the ones referenced by `fakeUserInvite` and `fakeUserToken` in order for Moq to return `fakeHttpResponseMessage`.

This is because [Moq's argument matching](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#matching-arguments) verifies that the arguments specified in the stub are *equal* to the ones made in the actual call. If they are not, the stub won't match and Moq will return the default value for the method's return type – in this case `null` since `HttpResponseMessage` is a reference type.

To solve this problem, you can either make sure that the `fakeUserInvite` and `fakeUserToken` references are being passed to the actual `service2.AddUser` call or you can use somewhat less specific [argument constraints](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#matching-arguments).

Here's an example:

```
service2.Setup(i => i.AddUser(
            It.Is<UserInvite>(u => u.EmailAddress == fakeEmail &&
                                   u.Username == fakeEmail),
            fakeUserToken))
        .ReturnsAsync(fakeHttpResponseMessage);
```

Here we're stating that the `AddUser` method should be called with:

1. A `UserInvite` object whose `EmailAddress` and `Username` properties have the same value as `fakeEmail` as the first argument
2. The same value as `fakeUserToken` as the second argument

If the actual values of those arguments don't matter to your specific test scenario, you can tell Moq to *always* return `fakeHttpResponseMessage` regardless of what arguments `AddUser` is being called with by saying:

```
service2.Setup(i => i.AddUser(
            It.IsAny<UserInvite>(),
            It.IsAny<string>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(fakeHttpResponseMessage);
```